# Two chrome windows and unexpected quit after running selenium chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have 3 files in my project: **main.py**, **g_webdriver.py**, and **whatever.py**. They look like this:

**main.py**:

```
import g_webdriver
import whatever

g_webdriver.run_chrome('https://stackoverflow.com')
```

**g_webdriver.py**:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

def run_chrome(url:str):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
```

**whatever.py**:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

If I run my main.py file, selenium opens two separate chrome windows: one with loaded stackoveflow website and one blank with `data:,` in url bar. Of course I want open only one window. How to fix this? Also I must mention that I tried to get rid of driver variable and open my chrome directly by `webdriver.Chrome()` but this approach doesn't work either because it opens two separate windows (one with loaded page and one blank) like in the first one and after a few seconds closing comes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run main, python imports `g_webdriver` and executes all code from that file including the line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

That's when the first window is opened.

Then python imports `whatever` and again runs `driver = webdriver.Chrome()`, so you get another separate window. `webdriver.Chrome()` always creates a new window.

At this point 2 windows are opened with blank pages and you open stackoverflow in `g_webdriver.driver`.

You could extract opening Chrome window to another file and import the one shared driver to both files:

chrome_window.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

g_webdriver.py:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from chrome_window import driver

def run_chrome(url:str):
    driver.get(url)
    driver.maximize_window()
```

whatever.py:

```
from chrome_window import driver
```